# Zero mean curvature and maximal volume

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, volume

I have a 1+1 asympotically flat spacetime system (spherical symmetry) for which I'm trying to find the hypersurface which maximizes the volume enclosed in a sphere of a given radius $r=R$.
**It seems that I'm able to find the equations defining such a surface and I can compute its mean extrinsic curvature. The latter comes out to be non-zero, in contradiction with what I knew about maximal hypersurface. 
However I'm not an expert on this topic and I would like your help.

**Precisely, I would like to know if there exists some theorem claiming that a hypersurface maximizes the volume *if and only if* the mean extrinsic curvature is null, i.e. $\kappa=0$.**

If the answer is positive, I would like to know which are the **hypotheses underlining the theorem**, in order to understand whether my system satisfies them and my computation is wrong or correct.

Comment: I removed the first sentence because by posting this question on this site, you are asking for an 'expert' to answer your question. There is no need to state such a hope when it's expected.